# How to use installed Packages from weka package manager?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am working on Weka 3.7.2 and I have issue using packages I install from package manager.

I go to weka package manager pick the package I want then click install and make sure loaded is set to Yes.

Restarted Weka and my laptop all together. Lets focus on NNge package.

[image]

Then going to explorer . Loading my data . When choosing classifier NNge, first it is in Grey and when I choose it, start button is not clickable.

[image]

Can someone points me to what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because you are using a numerical attribute as the class for your data. You need to change where it says "(Num) output" to something that says (Nom) instead of (Num) because (Nom) corresponds to a nominal (categorical) attribute, which is what you want. If you have more than one (Nom) please select the one that corresponds to the class attribute of your data. For the record, Num corresponds to numerical attributes and Nom corresponds to nominal attributes.